# How can I specify the default timezone in Crafter?

Tags: crafter-cms

When using a Date/Time control, it can have a timezone selector. But, when it doesn't, it has a default timezone (in my case, EST).

How does Crafter determine this default timezone? A config? from the server's settings?

And how can I change it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an admin:

1. Go to the preview or dashboard for a given site
2. Open the site content sidebar, select Admin console in v2.5 or Site settings in v3.x
3. Select the Configuration tool from the menu on the left, this will present a drop-down menu.
4. Select Site Configuration in the dropdown. This will show a configuration file. In that file you will see a configuration:

```html
    <default-timezone>EST5EDT</default-timezone>
```

This is the default timezone for that site.  Typically set to where the majority of the team managing the site sits. Set this value to a valid Java time zone locale.

5. Click the save button in the upper right to commit your changes.